# The Pivot point of every object is glued to the 3d Cursor

Tags: transforms, 3d-cursor

Sorry for that, but I have to interrupt your hopefully beautiful sunday, before I'm goin crazy.. :D In one of my projects (I'm a newbie) somehow I glued the pivot point of rotation to the 3d curosor (generally). If I select anything in my scene and push R, the center of the rotation is the 3d cursor, no exception. I attache some pictures, where you can see it. I'm sure somewhere somehow I used a shortkey accidentally, but google doesn't help, maybe you will. Extremly hard to work this way. Thank you!

[image: pic 1] [image: pic 3]

[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just changed your pivot point to 3D cursor.
It's the second dropdown menu on top of viewport.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, all of my family and friends are very grateful! : DD